# Adjusting header row color

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I use objectlistview in my project, in constructor I have a code like this :

```
foreach (OLVColumn item in olv.AllColumns)
{
    item.Width = -2;
    var headerstyle = new HeaderFormatStyle();
    headerstyle.SetFont(new Font(new FontFamily("Segoe UI"), 12.0f, FontStyle.Bold));
    headerstyle.SetBackColor(Color.FromArgb(16, 16, 16));
    headerstyle.SetForeColor(Color.White);
    item.HeaderFormatStyle = headerstyle;
}
```

This code gives a nice backcolor to my rows and sets the default values. This works and result is like this :

[image]

But at the end of the header row there is this:
[image]

There is a small gap with white(default) background color. I can fix this with making category column size a little bit bigger but the user is allowed to hide and change width of columns so this wont solve my problem. How can I reach to that white spot in code?
I have checked http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-do-i-change-the-font-or-color-of-the-column-headers but could not find the solution.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but there is a column property `FillsFreeSpace`. When you set it to `true` the respective column stretches to fill the whole OLV. That should remove the "gap".

Comment: FillsFreeSpace solved the problem, atleast it hides the white headerless part but I prefer to change that headerless part backcolor so I don't have to force the user to see column in whole listview, is there a way for it?

Comment: I do not think that is possible using native OLV functionality.. But an easy workaround would be to insert a dummy column with empty header text as last column, with `FillsFreeSpace` set to `true`.

Comment: That would be a good workaround but what about multiple selection with mouse drag? Since there is no header in that small part after category I am able to select multiple item with mouse drag. If I fill that gap with empty column as you said I won't be able to do mouse drag for multiple selection anymore. Also, I can't set FullRowSelect to false because my first column is an icon column therefore if I close FullRowSelect the selection becomes really hard to deal with.

Comment: Is having the last column selected in FullRowSelect really an issue? IMO it even looks better than a cut off selection line. I see your point with respect to drag-select. If you really need this, you will probably have to try and implement your own drag-select logic when clicking and holding anywhere in the OLV.

Comment: For me as programmer I prefer select start point and then hold shift before clicking my end point :) But for users they prefer to mouse drag, but I also see your point here. I will add an empty column to end use FillsFreeSpace for now. When I have time I'll try to implement my own mouse drag event over default one :) Can you please type your first comment as answer so I can mark it? btw, thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to make a column automatically fill the free horizontal space by setting the property `FillsFreeSpace` to `true`.

If it is not desirable to have one of the main columns stretching to the total width, a dummy column (with empty header text) that has `FillsFreeSpace` set to true could be inserted as the last column. it would probably be advisable to set `Hideable` and `IsEditable` to `false` for that column.